# widget with content from internal storage

Tags: android, widget, android-context

Have a widget that displays last saved photo in external memory of phone, there is class that reads photo from memory:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class PhotosReader {



    public PhotosReader() {
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(Context context) {
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
        };
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

        Bitmap bm = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(1));

        }
        return bm;
    }
}
```

with exact the same class on standard activity app I'm just making instance of that class and call the method, everything works perfectly fine:

```
 PhotosReader PR = new PhotosReader();
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        imageView.setImageBitmap(PR.getBitmap(this));
```

however when doing similar thing on WidgetProvider class:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);
    PhotosReader PR = new PhotosReader();

    views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, PR.getBitmap(context));
```

My widget is just en empty frame without any image.

inb4 permissions to read external storage are granted.

I'm assuming that problem is related with context

Comment: Perhaps the `Bitmap` is too large. Scale the `Bitmap` down using `BitmapFactory` and its `inSampleSize` field.

Comment: In other words: PR.getBitmap(context) will return null if the bitmap would become to big for available memory. Check for null to be shure.

Comment: Wonderful! it worked!  Thank you